# How to get Firebase collection data as dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dictionary, google-cloud-firestore

I want to read data from Firebase and return the output as a Dict to my ViewController.
I did not manage to get the data returned in a valid way.

**This is how I read the data:**

```
  func getCollectionData()  -> Dictionary<String, String> {
        var returnValue: String = ""
        
        db.collection(user).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                returnValue = ""
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    
                    let returnValue = document.data() as? Dictionary<String, String>
                    print (returnValue)
                }
            }
            
        }
        return returnValue
    }
```

Error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Dictionary<String, String>'
```

Why is `returnValue` String again?
I fiddled around a lot, but never found a solution, to return the data in a good way.

**The output of print(returnValue) shows it's a dictionary**

```
Optional(["url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/.....9c5e73f", "email": "a@b.com"])
```

**In my ViewController I want to use the data to fill a tableView:**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = Array(myReturnedDict.values)[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

**EDIT:**

I still get an empty Dictionary back as a returned value:

```
func getCollectionData()  -> Dictionary<String, String> {
        var returnValue = [String: String]()
        
        db.collection(user).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                returnValue = ["No":"data"]
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    print (user)
                    
                    returnValue = (document.data() as? Dictionary<String, String>)!
                                   
                    //print (returnValue)

                }
            }
            
        }
        return returnValue
}
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: func getCollectionData()  -> Dictionary<String, String>? {
        db.collection(user).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                return nil
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    return document.data() as? Dictionary<String, String>
                }
            }
        }
        return returnValue
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func getCollectionData(callback: @escaping(Dictionary<String, String>)  -> Void {
        db.collection(user).getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                callback(["No":"data"])
                return 
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    callback((document.data() as? Dictionary<String, String>)!)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You created `var returnValue: String = ""` and use it default value "".
To avoid it you need to change `returnValue` to type Dictionary<String, String> and set `returnValue` not like

```
let returnValue = document.data() as? Dictionary<String, String>
```

but

```
returnValue = document.data() as? Dictionary<String, String>
```

Comment: Hey, I edited my question. I still don't get back the content of returnValue. If I print it within the getCollectionData(), I see the content. But when it's returned it is an empty Dictionary.

Comment: Oh, I've found other issue. Your return is worked before your closure. So  you need to delete your return and add it after returnValue = (document.data() as? Dictionary<String, String>)!

Comment: But then I get "Unexpected non-void return value in void function!"

Comment: Sorry, you should use callbacks here